# angularjs ng-repeat use $index inside ng-model directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Try to use `ng-repeat`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "n in [1,2,3,4]>

     <label id="{{'p'+ n }}"> {{n}} </label>
     <label ng-model="{{'p'+ n }}"> {{n}} </label>

     </li>

</ul>
```

The first "label" works. Its "id" is assigned properly. But the second "label" doesn't work.

Is that because "ng-model" cannot be created dynamically?

I was trying to use `<select ng-model ... ng-options ...>` within a `ng-repeat`. Not being able to create these "ng-model" dynamically, I am stuck here.

Comment: Here are some tips on dynamically creating ng-models: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989453/how-to-give-value-dynamically-for-ng-model-in-angularjs

Comment: Zhe Hu.. please select the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model` is an Angular attribute, you don't need to include the `{{}}` -- try `ng-model="'p' + n"`

Comment: Somehow it still doesn't work. Inspecting html source, it shows `<label ng-model="p" +n class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding">1</label>`. In other words, "n" isn't expanded out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to reference $index

```
<li ng-repeat = "n in [1,2,3,4] ng-init="myIndex = $index">
  <label ng-model="{{'p'+ myIndex }}" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you have used `ng-model` on `label` tag which is not possible.

`ng-model` can be only used on `input, select and textarea` as per [This](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

you cannot use it on `div's, ul, ol, tabel etc`.

Instead, to assign the value in label you can use `ng-value` like this:

```
<label ng-value="{{'p'+ n }}"> {{n}} </label>
```

or to assign `index` value to `ng-model` you can do:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.text[$index]"/>
```

to display the index you can do:

```
{{$index}}
```